# Find the area bounded between $f(x)=\frac{\arctan(x)}{x^2}$ and $g(x)=\frac{\arctan(x)}{x^2+1}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, area

> Find the area bounded between $$f(x)=\frac{\arctan(x)}{x^2} \quad\text{and}\quad g(x)=\frac{\arctan(x)}{x^2+1}.$$

The title says the question. The limits are from 1 to infinity. I know that I must do this:
$$\int_1^\infty [f(x)-g(x)]\,dx$$

The integral of g(x) is trivial, it is a simple u-substitution.But for the integral of $f(x)$, I must do integration by parts. I set $u=arctan(x)$ and $dv=1/x^2$. The problem lies in the integral of udv:

$$\int^\infty_1\frac{1}{x(x^2+1)}dx$$
When we do the partial fraction decomp. we get:

$$\int^\infty_1\left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{x}{x^2+1}\right)dx$$

Now, we are going to get two natural logs, $$\ln(x), \quad \frac{1}{2} \ln(x^2+1).$$

Since this is going to infinity, won't the logs also go to infinity, leaving us with the volume being infinite? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Combine the logs to get $$\log{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}$$ and it should be clear what to do.

Comment: @Mattos oh it was so simple of a substitution that I converted it back with the same bounds of integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x \to \infty$,
$$\log \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \right) \to 0.$$

Comment: How, because we get $ln(\infty/\infty)$

Comment: @TanMath Rewriting gives that the expression on the l.h.s. is equal to $$\log \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{x^2}}} = -\frac{1}{2} \log \left(1 + \frac{1}{x^2}\right).$$

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ should, in infinite limit terms, be considered identical to $\sqrt{x^2}=x$. Thus the expression pointed out by @nayrb is equal to $\ln 1=0$.